# how do you hide nodes on initialization for a force directed graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I can't figure out how to hide child nodes on initialization. I want it so that if you click the parent, it will display its children.

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093130)?

Comment: yes, but the children are displayed when it is initialized. I've tried to hide them on initialization, but I get errors.